# ORA-30926 - Merge state

Tags: oracle, merge, distinct

I am getting an ORA-30926 error. I researched this and found that this is usually caused by duplicates in the query specified in the`USING` clause.

The problem is I am intially removing duplicates and storing in a temperory table (`temp_distinct`) which in turn I am referring to in the `MERGE`. Here is my code snippet:

```
MERGE INTO name_test nt 
USING (select name from temp_distinct) s 
ON (1=1)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN UPDATE SET nt.fn = s.name, nt.LN = s.name
```

Here is the structure of my tables:

`NAME_TEST`:

```
FN    LN
----- -----
Ruc   Rag
Ruc   Ran
Sam   Kum
Ruc   Ran
Ruc   Kum
Ran   Dev
Rag   Agar
Rag   Ran
```

`TEMP_DISTINCT`:

```
FN    NUMB NAME  NUM
----- ---- ----- ---
Sam   1    Mark  1
Rag   2    Steve 2
Dev   3    John  3
Kum   4    Dave  4
Ruc   5    Mich  5
Agar  6    Dean  6
Ran   7    Phil  7
```

So as you can see there is no duplicate in `USING` clause. I am trying to replace `NT.FN = S.NAME` and also `NT.LN = S.NAME`.

Basically I want to replace names in `FN` and `LN` from `NAME_TEST` table with different name from `TEMP_DISTINCT` table. Final output should be like below:

```
FN     LN
------ ------
Mich   Steve
Mich   Phil
Mark   Dave
Mich   Phil
Mich   Dave
Phil   John
Steve  Dean
Steve  Ran
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the explanation from @zaratustra, your merge is also attempting to set the `fn` and `ln` to the same `name` value so it wouldn't give the result you want even it worked. And you can't use `fn` or `ln` in the `using` clause as you're trying to update them.

If your `name_test` table had a primary key (or at least unique) column then you could include that in the merge, but you'd still only be able to correctly update either the `fn` or `ln` value in one pass.

I'm not sure why you're not doing a simple update:

```
update name_test nt
set fn = (select td.name from temp_distinct td where td.fn = nt.fn),
  ln = (select td.name from temp_distinct td where td.fn = nt.ln);

8 rows updated.

select * from name_test;

FN    LN  
----- -----
Mich  Steve 
Mich  Phil  
Mark  Dave  
Mich  Phil  
Mich  Dave  
Phil  John  
Steve Dean  
Steve Phil
```

Comment: This is a good idea. The merge operation is not what the author needs based on the shown input.

Answer (score 1):

Your query can't be executed because of `(1 = 1)` oracle can't get a stable set of rows, to be clear check this out:

```
SQL> create table ttt (name varchar2(20 char));

Table created.

SQL> insert into ttt values('first1');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into ttt values('second2');

1 row created.

SQL> merge into ttt t1 using (select 'name' name from dual) t2 on (1 = 1) when matched then update set t1.name = t2.name;

2 rows merged.

SQL> select * from ttt;

NAME
--------------------
name
name
```

There is only one row in the "t2" subquery and the merge operations has been successfully finished. But if your subquery gets you more than one line I will encounter the ORA-30926:

```
SQL> merge into ttt t1 using (select 'name' || level name from dual connect by rownum < 4) t2 on (1 = 1) when matched then update set t1.name = t2.name;
merge into ttt t1 using (select 'name' || level name from dual connect by rownum < 4) t2 on (1 = 1) when matched then update set t1.name = t2.name
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables


SQL> select * from ttt;

NAME
--------------------
name
name

SQL>
```

Oracle doesn't know what value has to be associated with the rows. Your result set is ambiguous. To be able to perform this merge you have to have a normal condition for example:

```
SQL> alter table ttt add id number(10);

Table altered.

SQL> update ttt set name = 'name1', id = rownum;

2 rows updated.

SQL> select * from ttt;

NAME                         ID
-------------------- ----------
name1                         1
name1                         2

SQL> merge into ttt t1 using (select 'name' name, level id from dual connect by rownum < 4) t2 on (t1.id = t2.id) when matched then update set t1.name = t2.name;

2 rows merged.

SQL> select * from ttt;

NAME                         ID
-------------------- ----------
name                          1
name                          2

SQL>
```

As you can see the "ttt" table  has been merged successfully.

Comment: Yes correct,, I thought that in ON clause the names will anyway be same. However, as @Alex suggested to directly use UPDATE rather than MERGE was easy. Anyways thanks for your pointing :) Appritiate it !! !!!

Comment: @user3360094, we are here to solve problems, 4 base operators (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/SELECT) can solve almost every your problems, oracle database has the most powerful SQL syntax. BTW, I have never used the merge clause for real projects.